# How to efficiently search and get item from array of objects using for\for each loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, search

I have 3 arrays, lets call them, A, B and C. A and B are arrays of strings and C is array of objects.

```
A = ['Geography1', 'Geography2', 'Geography3', ...];//length will range from 100 to 500.
B = ['Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018', 'Mar 2018' ...];//length will range from 12 to 36.
C = [
   {"geoName": "Geography1", "month": "Jan 2018", "sales": 1, "growth": 12.11, "marketShare": 13.11},
{"geoName": "Geography1", "month": "Feb 2018", "sales": 2, "growth": 22.22, "marketShare": 23.22},
....
....
....
{"geoName": "Geography2", "month": "Jan 2018", "sales": 3, "growth": 33.33, "marketShare": 12.4},
{"geoName": "Geography2", "month": "Feb 2018", "sales": 4, "growth": 23.45, "marketShare": 12.4},
....
....
....
....
]; length will be A.length * B.length, approximately it will range from 1,200 to 18,000.
```

Using those arrays and based on either 'sales' or 'growth', I need to generate another array, say D, which needs to have following format(shown values are for 'sales', if we filter by growth, growth values need to be shown againt each geography\month), using for or for each loop:

```
D = [
{"geoName":"Geography1", "Jan 2018": 1, "Feb 2018":2,....},
{"geoName":"Geography2", "Jan 2018": 3, "Feb 2018":4,....},
....
...

....
];
```

Currently this is how my code looks, but it's not efficient for large datasets. It takes long time to execute:

```
function formatData(){
    D = [];
    var displayBy = "sales"; //or "growth"
    for each(geoDesc in A)
            {
                var row = {};
                row['geoName']= geoDesc;

                var val:Number;


                for each(var month:String in B)
                {

                    val = getValue(C, month, geoDesc, displayBy)
                    row[month] = val;

                }

                D.push(row);
            }
//D here will have final output
}

function getValue(source:Array, month:String, geoDesc:String,displayBy:String):Number
            {
                var value:Number = 0;
                var len:int = source.length;
                for(var i:int = 0; i < len; i++)
                {
                    var item:Object = source[i];
                    if(item['month'] == month && item['geoName'] == geoDesc)
                    {
                        value = item[displayBy];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return value; 
}
```

Comment: I think that your question is too unclear. Could you explain once more how A, B and C merge to D?

Comment: Using the arrays A, B and C, I need to create a new array, D. Array A is used to get geography names, B is used to get month names and C has the data. Using those 3 arrays, I need to create D(with given format of D).